# Mongo exit code 45, can't start mongod, MongoDB cannot open or obtain a lock on a file

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

My Meteor application keeps crashing with this message when I type `mrt` (`mrt` should start the Meteor application):

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 45. Restarting.

Unexpected mongo exit code 45. Restarting.

Unexpected mongo exit code 45. Restarting.

Can't start mongod

MongoDB cannot open or obtain a lock on a file
```

Doing it with `sudo mrt`, it works.

I got to this error after fixing other erros. I fixed the errors I got before by typing:

`sudo chmod -R 777 ./`

Before, I had other errors. But now I do not know what it could be as there shouldn't be differences between root and my user in that directory.

For Non-Meteor users: Meteor has a little mongodb in its `.meteor` directory.

*What could be the reason?*

**This is the requested output from `ls -Rl .meteor/ | grep root` executed as a normal user :**

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 local
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  220 Jan  3 11:51 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Dec 29 12:35 release
drwxrwxrwx 4 root    root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 build
drwxrwxrwx 2 vagrant root 4096 Dec 29 12:39 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  151 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 programs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  650 Jan  3 19:59 README
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 server
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  459 Jan  3 19:59 star.json
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 client
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 ctl
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 server
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5836 Jan  3 19:59 app.html
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16184 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1429 Jan  3 19:59 main.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4153 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  395 Jan  3 19:59 template.main.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  337 Jan  3 19:59 template.templates.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17848 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.pack.js
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 styles
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2552 Jan  3 19:59 default.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1557 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     131 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10296 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4344 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30962 Jan  3 19:59 check.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13769 Jan  3 19:59 check.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34115 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12796 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59298 Jan  3 19:59 domutils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25408 Jan  3 19:59 domutils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   67567 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21692 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1562 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     125 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48406 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15990 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     493 Jan  3 19:59 global-imports.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37547 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16703 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1202072 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  366987 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   58410 Jan  3 19:59 json.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21539 Jan  3 19:59 json.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  560614 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  189125 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   62132 Jan  3 19:59 liverange.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29655 Jan  3 19:59 liverange.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27875 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10321 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  102074 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33820 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   82210 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26826 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  323368 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  121486 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  102219 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39683 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20462 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7503 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53364 Jan  3 19:59 page-js-ie-support.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13636 Jan  3 19:59 page-js-ie-support.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    2558 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     471 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21800 Jan  3 19:59 random.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8299 Jan  3 19:59 random.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13878 Jan  3 19:59 reactive-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    5176 Jan  3 19:59 reactive-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19595 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7551 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44685 Jan  3 19:59 router.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13728 Jan  3 19:59 router.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3314 Jan  3 19:59 session.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     661 Jan  3 19:59 session.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  204184 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   83409 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1466 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     114 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1457 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     124 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1356 Jan  3 19:59 startup.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     108 Jan  3 19:59 startup.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24071 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9422 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  147815 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   54556 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59722 Jan  3 19:59 universal-events.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28310 Jan  3 19:59 universal-events.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1355 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     107 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6411 Jan  3 19:59 boot.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jan  3 19:59 config.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 npm
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2603 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2716 Jan  3 19:59 start.sh
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 logging
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/ctl-helper/d6214568fb/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/livedata/f69d9149dd/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/logging/04f04cd832/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14673 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5102 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29768 Jan  3 19:59 check.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13747 Jan  3 19:59 check.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21450 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8410 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14131 Jan  3 19:59 ctl.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5110 Jan  3 19:59 ctl.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  32921 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12774 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  66343 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21669 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26264 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9274 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  47212 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15968 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    159 Jan  3 19:59 json.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     83 Jan  3 19:59 json.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 486950 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 159409 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26681 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10299 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 117915 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  38384 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 345015 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 129871 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 366752 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 143322 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19268 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7481 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20606 Jan  3 19:59 random.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8277 Jan  3 19:59 random.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 146621 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  54534 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js.map
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6411 Jan  3 19:59 boot.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   70 Jan  3 19:59 config.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 npm
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4508 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2716 Jan  3 19:59 start.sh
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4153 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17848 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.pack.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 logging
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 router
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 webapp
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/handlebars/0a8b732b9d/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/livedata/f69d9149dd/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/logging/04f04cd832/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /var/www/tk/packages/router/.build/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/webapp/06c8311d2d/npm/node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14673 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5102 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8244 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   4008 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29768 Jan  3 19:59 check.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13747 Jan  3 19:59 check.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  32921 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12774 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  66343 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21669 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26264 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9274 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  47212 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15968 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    588 Jan  3 19:59 global-imports.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16964 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8220 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    161 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     85 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    159 Jan  3 19:59 json.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     83 Jan  3 19:59 json.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 486950 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 159409 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26681 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10299 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  99884 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  33617 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 117915 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  38384 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 345015 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 129871 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 366752 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 143322 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19268 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7481 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    203 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     95 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20606 Jan  3 19:59 random.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8277 Jan  3 19:59 random.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    161 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     85 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15797 Jan  3 19:59 routepolicy.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5460 Jan  3 19:59 routepolicy.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35844 Jan  3 19:59 router.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10422 Jan  3 19:59 router.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    162 Jan  3 19:59 session.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     86 Jan  3 19:59 session.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    160 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     84 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13828 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5456 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    227 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    101 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    165 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     89 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 146621 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  54534 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  83198 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  30430 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16777216 Jan  3 19:59 local.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33554432 Dec 29 12:36 local.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16777216 Jan  3 19:59 local.ns
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4 Dec 29 12:36 METEOR-PORT
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root        0 Jan  3 21:05 mongod.lock
```

And here as root:

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 local
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  220 Jan  3 11:51 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Dec 29 12:35 release
drwxrwxrwx 4 root    root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 build
drwxrwxrwx 2 vagrant root 4096 Dec 29 12:39 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  151 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 programs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  650 Jan  3 19:59 README
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 server
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  459 Jan  3 19:59 star.json
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 client
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 ctl
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 server
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5836 Jan  3 19:59 app.html
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16184 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1429 Jan  3 19:59 main.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4153 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  395 Jan  3 19:59 template.main.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  337 Jan  3 19:59 template.templates.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17848 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.pack.js
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jan  3 19:59 styles
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2552 Jan  3 19:59 default.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1557 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     131 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10296 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4344 Jan  3 19:59 autoupdate.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30962 Jan  3 19:59 check.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13769 Jan  3 19:59 check.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34115 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12796 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59298 Jan  3 19:59 domutils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25408 Jan  3 19:59 domutils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   67567 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21692 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1562 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     125 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48406 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15990 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     493 Jan  3 19:59 global-imports.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37547 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16703 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1202072 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  366987 Jan  3 19:59 jquery.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   58410 Jan  3 19:59 json.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21539 Jan  3 19:59 json.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  560614 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  189125 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   62132 Jan  3 19:59 liverange.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29655 Jan  3 19:59 liverange.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27875 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10321 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  102074 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33820 Jan  3 19:59 marked.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   82210 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26826 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  323368 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  121486 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  102219 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39683 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20462 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7503 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53364 Jan  3 19:59 page-js-ie-support.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13636 Jan  3 19:59 page-js-ie-support.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    2558 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     471 Jan  3 19:59 preserve-inputs.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21800 Jan  3 19:59 random.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8299 Jan  3 19:59 random.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13878 Jan  3 19:59 reactive-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    5176 Jan  3 19:59 reactive-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19595 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7551 Jan  3 19:59 reload.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44685 Jan  3 19:59 router.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13728 Jan  3 19:59 router.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3314 Jan  3 19:59 session.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     661 Jan  3 19:59 session.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  204184 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   83409 Jan  3 19:59 spark.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1466 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     114 Jan  3 19:59 spiderable.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1457 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     124 Jan  3 19:59 standard-app-packages.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1356 Jan  3 19:59 startup.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     108 Jan  3 19:59 startup.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24071 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9422 Jan  3 19:59 templating.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  147815 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   54556 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59722 Jan  3 19:59 universal-events.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28310 Jan  3 19:59 universal-events.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1355 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     107 Jan  3 19:59 webapp.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6411 Jan  3 19:59 boot.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jan  3 19:59 config.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 npm
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2603 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2716 Jan  3 19:59 start.sh
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 logging
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/ctl-helper/d6214568fb/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/livedata/f69d9149dd/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/logging/04f04cd832/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14673 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5102 Jan  3 19:59 application-configuration.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29768 Jan  3 19:59 check.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13747 Jan  3 19:59 check.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21450 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8410 Jan  3 19:59 ctl-helper.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14131 Jan  3 19:59 ctl.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   5110 Jan  3 19:59 ctl.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  32921 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12774 Jan  3 19:59 deps.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  66343 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21669 Jan  3 19:59 ejson.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26264 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9274 Jan  3 19:59 follower-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  47212 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15968 Jan  3 19:59 geojson-utils.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    159 Jan  3 19:59 json.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     83 Jan  3 19:59 json.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 486950 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 159409 Jan  3 19:59 livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26681 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10299 Jan  3 19:59 logging.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 117915 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  38384 Jan  3 19:59 meteor.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 345015 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 129871 Jan  3 19:59 minimongo.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 366752 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 143322 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19268 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7481 Jan  3 19:59 ordered-dict.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20606 Jan  3 19:59 random.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8277 Jan  3 19:59 random.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 146621 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  54534 Jan  3 19:59 underscore.js.map
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6411 Jan  3 19:59 boot.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   70 Jan  3 19:59 config.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 npm
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 packages
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4508 Jan  3 19:59 program.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2716 Jan  3 19:59 start.sh
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 app
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4153 Jan  3 19:59 main.js
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17848 Jan  3 19:59 highlight.pack.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 handlebars
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 logging
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 mongo-livedata
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 router
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 webapp
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/handlebars/0a8b732b9d/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/livedata/f69d9149dd/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/logging/04f04cd832/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /root/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules -> /var/www/tk/packages/router/.build/npm/node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 19:59 main
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Jan  3 19:59 node_modules ->
```

--- cut off because of limits ---

Comment: sounds like a problem with permissions. Could you run `ls -Rl .meteor/ | grep root` and post the output. Probably your journal files are set to root. Once you run as root, there will be files that will belong to root.

Comment: Thank you for checking that. I posted the information according to your request.

Comment: it should be obvious now that there are files owned by root that shouldn't be.

Comment: Why is that a problem if I set rights to 777 so that everyone can write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of steps to reinstall meteor and meteorite

Uninstall meteor

- sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
- rm -rf ~/.meteor

Uninstall meteorite

- `sudo mrt uninstall`
- `sudo mrt uninstall --system`
- sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm

The last command is to make sure that `~/.npm` permissions are correct.

Install meteor

`curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`

Install meteorite

`sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't solve the stated problem. It's great to have an uninstall procedure though.

To be more precise, the error is *mostly* related to permissions with the Mongo database instance installed by Meteor. Removing everything Meteor could help, but didn't in my case. For the record, the problem is within a specific app. New Meteor apps do work OK

Answer (score 8):

MongoDb won't run in the Vagrant shared directory: https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677

If you using Windows for your dev work, Meteor now has a Windows installer:
http://win.meteor.com/

Comment: Which is good, but unfortunately doesn't fix the users problem. Plus if you type "meteor add-platform android" in Windows you are told it is not yet supported, so Meteor for windows is only partway there...

Comment: If a user is unable to run MongoDb in the Vagrant shared directory and the user needs to run Meteor (or another platform) within the Vagrant VM, then the user will have to use a work around such as copying the data to a non-shared folder within the Vagrant VM. I realize my answer is not a complete solution, but it points out a possible problem for using Meteor within Vagrant.

Answer (score 3):

Mongo was killed without cleaning itself up. Try removing .meteor/local/db/mongod.lock. If that fails do an **meteor reset.**

Answer (score 2):

There are files owned by root that shouldn't be. Run the following to set the ownership back to the current user (who I am assuming to be the one who is meant to run mrt):

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:`groups | cut -d ' '  -f 1` *
```

Comment: It's great that I know get another error, so it seems to have solved the former one. I ran it inside the folder and there is, unfortunately, still a problem, I get: `/home/vagrant/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173, Error: EACCES, permission denied 'myAppFolderInWhichIRanTheCommand/packages/marked'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)...`

Comment: I just checked it: All rights in `/home/vagrant` are correctly set and `myUser` is owner of all files in there.

Comment: Setting the ownership of the `.meteor/local` directory and everything under it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example @tsega?

Comment: Assuming you're in your meteor app directory, `sudo chown YOU_USER_NAME -R .meteor/local` replace YOUR_USER_NAME with your actual user name so for me it would as follows, `sudo chown tsega -R .meteor/local`. If you want to see who actually owns the directories/files you can issue the command `ls -l .meteor`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

First I changed permissions sudo `chown -Rv <user> .meteor` and then `meteor reset`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works, when running the meteor application as root-user.

```
su root 
meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using meteor with docker and created meteor app in a mounted directory which was not under home directory.
Resolved itself, when i created the app in a directory under home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use vagrant as development environment. When building application under /vagrant, this error always happens. When I switch to /home/vagrant, then this error is solved. 
I think this is caused by permission, but since /vagrant is also mapped by vagrant account, so there is no difference.

I still didn't figure out why.